# What are the effective ways to maintain the background running tasks in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jobs

I have some tasks that will take more than 30 minutes to complete. I have no idea about how to maintain this kind of tasks.Please help me on this

Comment: Probably best not to put them on a web server anyways. Let your web server handle web requests. Put background processing on an application server.

Comment: Since you decided not to include results of your research (i.e. https://www.google.com/search?q=background+running+tasks+in+asp.net) it is hard to see what you've already tried. So default duplicate should cover basics - feel free to demonstrate results of your research in future questions.

Answer (score 3):

I have used [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) for one of my projects for background task, and I found it extremely good.

Hangfire is an open-source framework that helps you to create, process and manage your background jobs. It comes with out of the box dashboard to track your background job and many more cool feature.

The documentation is very good to get started with the tool.
You can find the documentation [here](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be asynchronous as well as distributed(Possibly). In our project we use `Akka.Net` to do such tasks. It uses the actor model which are essentially part of the code you ask to do your long `async` tasks out of sight in the background.

http://getakka.net/

http://getakka.net/docs/Getting%20started

```
var greeter = system.ActorOf<GreetingActor>("greeter");
greeter.Tell(new Greet("World"));
```

In place of `GreetingActor`, you'll have your long running process and on the second line of code, you pass it a message which tells it to run `async`. There is also a `<actor>.Ask()` in cases when you need it to be `synchronous`.